# CPU spike when transitioning from a still image

Tags: ffmpeg, libx264

After streaming a still image (with x264) for a long period of time, the transition to live video makes the CPU spike to 100% for a period of time proportionally equal to how long the still image was streaming.  More specifically, transitioning after a minute will result in a CPU spike lasting about 15 seconds.  Transitioning after 30 minutes will result in that spike lasting closer to 3 minutes.

Does this symptom make any sense and is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: How can we duplicate this issue?

Comment: Duplicating will be difficult but I could try to extract all of this code into a stand-alone C program.  I'll start on that but in the mean time, does this symptom make any sense?  Is there some kind of cache that I should clear or the concept of a discontinuity flag that I need to set when making the transition from the still image?

Comment: Looks like this is related to gop_size.  Any suggestions for gop_size for fast-ish motion video?  Will setting AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY force a new GOP?